# inspect.stack() return path value with slash and backslash

Tags: python, inspect

I'm trying to iterate on `inspect.stack()` in order to get the file hierarchy.

**A simple example:**

```
for value in inspect.stack():
    print value[1]
```

**The output will be:**

```
C:\xxx\ATE\Utilities\Simulator\Simulator.py
C:\xxx\ATE\Utilities\Simulator\Simulator.py
C:\xxx\ATE\Utilities\Simulator\serial.py
C:\xxx\ATE\Utilities\Serial\SerialHandle\trunk\SerialHandle.py
C:/xxx/ATE/DUTDrivers/DD_SimulatorExample/DD_Example_Simulator.py
```

Now i'm removing the file names using string manipulations, and using the path names in my software.

**Question:**

Why there there are some paths with slash (\) and some with backslash (/)?

Note: I know i can do a simple string manipulation using `replace` to replace the backslash to slash or just use `os.path.normpath(path)` but i'm trying to understand why the `inspect.stack` module returns it that way?

Comment: How do you start DD_Example_Simulator.py? Cmd.exe, Idle, something else?

Comment: @Nigel Tufnel +1 at cmd.exe mode it works fine! if someone knows why with pycharm it happens this way it will be grate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that PyCharm starts `DD_Example_Simulator.py` using full path and forward slashes (/).

That's why you see forward slashes only in `DD_Example_Simulator.py` path (the rest of the paths are built by Python interpreter and thus have proper Windows backslashes). As a side note: using forward slashes is perfectly OK on Windows. Well, at least my copy of Windows doesn't mind the forward slashes.

Let's have an expirement using cmd.exe.

Let's create two files.

First:

```
// inspectso.py
import inspect

for value in inspect.stack():
    print value[1]
```

Second:

```
// inspect_so.py
import inspectso
```

The final step of the expirement: run these commands in cmd:

```
e:\Temp>c:/Python27/python.exe E:/temp/inspect_so.py
E:\temp\inspectso.py
E:/temp/inspect_so.py

e:\Temp>c:/Python27/python.exe E:\temp\inspect_so.py
E:\temp\inspectso.py
E:\temp\inspect_so.py

e:\Temp>c:/Python27/python.exe inspect_so.py
e:\Temp\inspectso.py
inspect_so.py
```

As we can see the path to `inspect_so.py` is printed as it was passed on command line and the path to `inspectso.py` is always severely backslashed.